# Reference Frames

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, inertial-frames, relative-motion

I observe two cars approaching each other from opposite directions and measure as 40 mph and 30 mph, respectively. How fast is the 40 mph car moving according to the driver in the 30 mph car? Apparently, the gap is closing at a rate of 70 mph, so the 30 mph car sees the 40 mph car approach at a rate of 70 mph. Can someone please explain this? Why wouldn't the 30 mph car see the 40 mph car at a rate of 40 mph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say I'm on the ground (not in either car) and the first car is a mile way and heading towards me. I start my stopwatch and measure that it takes 1.5 minutes (1/40 hours) for the car to reach me.  Speed is distance / time = 1 mile / (1/40 hours) = 40 mph.

Now say I'm in the second car and the first car is a mile away and heading towards me. I start my stopwatch and measure that it takes 1/70 hours (something less than a minute) for the car to reach me. Speed = distance / time = 1 mile / (1/70 hours) = 70 mph.

The speed I measure depends on my frame of reference (where I am).

In this experiment you could tell quite easily, even if you were in the second car, what the speedometer in the first car would be showing -- 40 mph.  But that is the speed relative to the ground, not relative to an observer in the second car.

Answer (score 0):

In the classical perspective, think of it this way.
An observer will always think it is *at rest*, but in the process other moving objects will have added or subtracted speeds. Now for the cars moving towards each other the 30 mph car( lets call it A) will think it is at rest( principle and fact of any relative motion) but why do they measure speed of 40 mph car( lets call it B) to be 70 mph?

To understand fully, understand how speed is measured: By observing the distance moved by another object per unit time. To the A, it is itself at rest, but due to its 30 mph speed to **A** it *seems* that the distance travelled by B is *more*( as for a speed of 70 mph) per unit time. Thus, to **A**, the speed of **B** appears more, that is their addition of speeds= 70 mph.

Answer (score 0):

If both cars move at 40 mph with respect to you, you will not see them moving away from each other, they will remain at the same distance from each other. And they will think the same, they will not think that the other is moving away at 40mph and therefore increase their distance